# microphone keeps auto adjusting from 100 to 0

Tags: windows-10, updates, microphone, recording, audio-recording

I have a microphone that i use to talk on microsoft teams for online learning, however recently after updating some things on my windows 10 computer. It is a:

edition: windows 10 enterprise

version: 1703

OS build: 15063.786

i have been on all of these forums and done all the things and nothing works:

[How do I disable microphone volume auto-adjusting?](https://superuser.com/questions/362343/how-do-i-disable-microphone-volume-auto-adjusting)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/mic-keeps-automatically-adjusting-on-windows-10/cd02fb61-9645-402d-bcd0-319fee369da2 (this is most like the issue i am having and it has not been solved)

https://appuals.com/how-to-stop-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-windows-10/

My microphone is still automatically changing to 0 from 100 constantly. I found something out that if I mute my microphone on Microsoft teams it stays at 100 until it goes to 0 again but when I leave the call it also auto goes to 0. When I join it works for about 5 seconds until it goes down instantly and repeatedly. There is no malware on my computer. I really need help. I cant do my school work if I cant talk. My microphone is an audiotechnica microphone and so i can usually talk and have a clear sound from about a foot away. I discovered (even though the microphone is at 0 and 2 constantly) if i go closer to the microphone it does work. Propably because of it being at 2 but i just thought to share this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that this was heppening from microsoft teams even though i disabled it to make changes to my microphone. What i do when my mic is now going to 0 is I press on my profile and go to settings then to devices and make a test call. I then talk for about 30 seconds and then stop. A beep will happen and then it will play back make sure to listen to the playback until you can hear yourself talking. Then i go back to the call and its fixed! You are going to need to do this every time you adjust your speaker. So if you have microsoft teams open or your trying to talk on microsoft teams then thats propably the issue. However if your struggling with the same issue with other programs then sorry but i dont know how you could fix that.